# Как скопировать значение ячейки таблицы в буффер обмена

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно по нажатию на ячейку таблица скопировать ее содержимое в буффер обмена, как это сделать? Можно пример с JQuery

Comment: Вам нужно - пишите сами. Или нанимайте кого-нибудь.

Comment: @Other извещать об этом в столь резкой форме не стоит.

Comment: @Regent, таких просителей много, нервов не так много. Хотя форма не очень уж резкая. **Не располагающая** - точнее будет.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример таблицы (HTML+CSS). Если вы пытались  решить задачу самостоятельно, код попытки тоже стоит добавить в вопрос.

Comment: @Other а я пытался трясти с авторов вопросов примеры их попыток решения задачи самостоятельно или объяснения, почему они не пытались решить сами. В простых и понятных вопросах проще, быстрее и с меньшими затратами нервов выходит дать ответ.

Comment: @Regent, по печальному опыту можно судить что это не в силах помочь. Обычно слышу что-то типа "Ну пабрацки сделай, сложно что ли?".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript